# Using JPA, what would cause a new row to be created rather an existing row being updated?

Tags: java, jpa

When my application comes up, it checks if the entity (of which there should be at most one) exists. If it does not, a new entity is created and persisted. I call `EntityManager.persist()` (and I have experimentally tried `merge()` also) the entity, expecting when I stop the application and look at the corresponding table to find a single row but instead I find a row for each persist or merge call. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Inserting**:

- The entity is **not** read from `EntityManager`
- The ID is `null` (in case it's primitive, like `int`, it is `0`)
- You call `EntityManager.persist()`
- You call `EntityManager.flush()`

**Updating**:

- The entity is read from `EntityManager` (either by `find` or by executing query)
- You change some fields of it
- You call `EntityManager.flush()`